# Get value from combobox

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have 2 tables in the database `carrier` and `vendor`. `vendor` has a foreign key of `Carrier_Id`. When the user want add a vendor, the user will select a carrier from a combobox where the valve from carrier table.

The problem I facing now is that,I don't know how to get the valve from combobox so that I can insert it into the database.

I use this code to get valve from carrier table to show in the combobox.

```
MyinvoiceDataDataContext contect = new MyinvoiceDataDataContext();
var st = from s in contect.Carriers
select new { s.CarrierID, s.CarrierName};
comVendorCarrier.ItemsSource = st;
comVendorCarrier.DisplayMemberPath = "CarrierName";
comVendorCarrier.SelectedValuePath = "CarrierID";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of this combobox (i.e. the selected carrier), all you need is just use the two properties `SelectedValue` to get the `CarrierId` or `SelectedText` to get the value (i.e. `CarrierName`).
For example, you could get the id of the selected carrier by using:

```
int SelectedCarrierId = int.parse(comVendorCarrier.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Or if you need the `CarrierName` you should use:

```
string CarrierName = comVendorCarrier.SelectedText;
```

**Edit:** Assuming that your tables have the following structre:

**Carrier:**

- `CarrierId`.
- `CarrierName`.

**Vendor:**

- `VendorId`.
- `CarrierId`: a foreign key references Carriers(CarrierId).
- `VendorName`.

These two tables should be mapped in your *.dbml* file to two entities `Vendor` and `Carrier`, in which the `Vendor` class has a property of type `Carrier` that represents the foreign key `CarrierID`.

Then in order to view `CarrierName` in the vendors list, you can do this:

```
var vendorsList = _db.Vendors 
                     .Select( vendor => new
                     {
                         VendorId = vendor.Id,
                         VendorName = vendor.Name,
                         CarrierName = vendor.Carrier.Name
                     });
```

Comment: I gettng this error; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @ThivakaranSelvarajoo, is your data is populated correctly on the combobox??

Comment: @ThivakaranSelvarajoo, What object is giving this error is it the `comVendorCarrier`?

Comment: But now i having one more problem here. If i want to view the vendor list, the carrier name showing carrierID. What i have to do so that when i click view vendor, the carrier Name must show the carrier name and not carrierID..Thanks in advance

Comment: I have one more problem right now. Im getting this error "ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException" when im trying to edit the carrier name.

Comment: @ThivakaranSelvarajoo, This exception happeded when you try to edit or change a field like carriername that is an entity referenced by the vendor. Instead of editing one field, you need to load the entire entity that you need to edit not just one field.

Comment: Im calling all the vendor entity since i want to edit vendor information. Its error will appear when only i try to change the carrier name in vendor. Pls see my code at bottam. Thanks.

Comment: @ThivakaranSelvarajoo, That's it don't change the carrier name in vendor, becouse it is not stored in the vendor table, it is an entity `Carrier` that is referenced in the `vendor` class, (i.g) the foriegn key `carrier_id` so all what you want is get back the all entity the update it's name in the carriers table, and it is already referenced in the vendor table so your edit will be done like this.

Comment: @MGA...I dont really understand the answer.

Comment: @MGA.. Please look at here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885568/updating-error-using-ling-to-sql/9885642#comment12649434_9885642

Answer (score 0):

```
using (MyinvoiceDataDataContext connv = new MyinvoiceDataDataContext())
            {

                Vendor editven = (from s in connv.Vendors
                                 where s.VendorID == vendor.VendorID
                                 select s).FirstOrDefault();

                editven.VendorAddress = editven.VendorAddress;
                editven.VendorBalance = editven.VendorBalance;
                editven.VendorContactName = editven.VendorContactName;
                editven.VendorEmail = editven.VendorEmail;
                editven.VendorFax = editven.VendorFax;
                editven.VendorName = editven.VendorName;
                editven.VendorPaymentTerms = editven.VendorPaymentTerms;
                editven.VendorPhone = editven.VendorPhone;
                editven.VendorRemark = editven.VendorRemark;
                editven.VendorTax = editven.VendorTax;
                editven.VendorWebsite = editven.VendorWebsite;
                editven.CarrierID = editven.CarrierID;
                connv.SubmitChanges();

            }
```